# Cprogram to print an English ruler

Tags: c, loops

In this i have been tasked to Write a C program to draw an English Ruler whose lengths as well as orientation(horizontal/vertical) is given by the user.
I wrote a program that prints the ruler vertically, and i wanted to write another program that prints it horizontally, then i join the two programs using if functions.
but the program for printing the ruler horizontally is not coming out well. I need some help.
This is the program that prints the ruler vertically.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
  int q,num,x;
  int y,p,n;
  printf("Enter height of central dashes\n");
  scanf("%d",&n);
  printf("Enter number of inches\n");
  scanf("%d",&num);
  for(x=0;x<num;x++)
  {
    for(q=0;q<n;q++)
    {
      printf("-");
    }
    printf("%d\n",x);
    for(p=0;p<n-3;p++)
    {
      printf("-");
    }
    printf("\n");
    for(p=0;p<n-2;p++)
    {
      printf("-");
    }
    printf("\n");
    for(p=0;p<n-3;p++)
    {
      printf("-");
    }
    printf("\n");
    for(p=0;p<n-1;p++)
    {
      printf("-");
    }
    printf("\n");
    for(p=0;p<n-3;p++)
    {
      printf("-");
    }
    printf("\n");
    for(p=0;p<n-2;p++)
    {
      printf("-");
    }
    printf("\n");
    for(p=0;p<n-3;p++)
    {
      printf("-");
    }
    printf("\n");
  }
  for(y=0;y<n;y++)
  {
    printf("-");
  }
  printf("%d",x);
  printf("\n");
  return 0;
}
```

I need some ideas on how i can print this ruler horizontally.
Probably using loops.
This is the program that i wrote to print out the ruler horizontally. But it can only print for the interval of 1 inch.Sorry about the indentation, couldnt edit it

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
int q,num,x;
int y,p,n=9;
printf("Enter number of inches\n");
scanf("%d",&num);
for(x=1;x<=num;x++)
{
for(q=1;q<=n-8;q++)
{
printf(" | ");
}
for(q=2;q<=n-1;q++)
{
printf("   ");
}
for(q=9;q<=n-0;q++)
{
printf(" | ");
}
printf("\n");
for(q=1;q<=n-8;q++)
{
printf(" | ");
}
for(q=2;q<=n-5;q++)
{
printf("   ");
}
for(q=5;q<=5;q++)
{
printf(" | ");
}
for(q=6;q<=n-1;q++)
{
printf("   ");
}
for(q=9;q<=n;q++)
{
printf(" | ");
}
printf("\n");
for(q=1;q<=n-8;q++)
{
printf(" | ");
}
for(q=2;q<=n-7;q++)
{
printf("   ");
}
for(q=3;q<=n-6;q++)
{
printf(" | ");
}
for(q=4;q<=n-5;q++)
{
printf("   ");
}
for(q=5;q<=n-4;q++)
{
printf(" | ");
}
for(q=6;q<=n-3;q++)
{
printf("   ");
}
for(q=7;q<=n-2;q++)
{
printf(" | ");
}
for(q=8;q<=n-1;q++)
{
printf("   ");
}
for(q=9;q<=n;q++)
{
printf(" | ");
}
printf("\n");
for(q=1;q<=n;q++)
{
printf(" | ");
}
printf("");
}
return 0;
}
```

[This is the output for horizontal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KdUKi.png)

[this is the output for vertical](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jukFd.png)

Comment: Please do edit and fix your code indentation, it would be much easier to understand and read the code then.

Comment: If the vertical is fine better show the program for horizontal as [mre]. Then describe in detail what you mean by "the ruler horizontally is not coming out well".

Comment: @mediocrevegetable1 The currently shown code is irrelevant. But yes, I also would like the MRE to be consistently indented.

Comment: The info in your picture is textual. Please show it as text directly here. If you do that you might find out about how to do that via program. If not describe the difference of what you want to what you get in English. That also is a good way to get you started with ideas how to do it in a program.

Comment: I've edited the first part of the source code, using the "edit" button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of giving out the whole answer for your homework question, here is a head start. The following program prints a ruler in C using recursion. Try playing with the code to make it fit your task and needs. The code has been taken from a book

### Code:

```
//using recursion to subdivisionside a ruler
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

const int len = 66;
const int divisions = 5;
void subdivisionside(char ar[], int min, int max, int level);

int main()
{
    char ruler[len];
    int i;
    for (int i = 1; i < (len - 2); i++)
        ruler[i] = ' ';
    ruler[len - 1] = '\0';

    int min = 0;
    int max = len - 2;
    ruler[min] = ruler[max] = '|';

    printf("%s\n", ruler);

    for (i = 1; i <= divisions; i++)
    {
        subdivisionside(ruler, min, max, i);
        printf("%s\n", ruler);
        for (int j = 1; j < len - 2; j++)
            ruler[j] = ' ';
    }

    return 0;
}

void subdivisionside(char ar[], int low, int high, int level)
{
    if (level == 0)
        return;
    int mid = (high + low) / 2;
    ar[mid] = '|';
    subdivisionside(ar, low, mid, level - 1);
    subdivisionside(ar, mid, high, level - 1);
}
```

### Current Output:

```
|                                                               |
|                               |                               |
|               |               |               |               |
|       |       |       |       |       |       |       |       |
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
| | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | |
```

Ref: [C++ Recursive function for printing a ruler not working.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6867349/c-recursive-function-for-printing-a-ruler-not-working)

Hope this helps and happy coding!

Comment: Thanks alot, ill build on this.

Comment: can you pls, explain to me how they came up with this code, or atleast give me a referance of the book where you got it from.